# Can I access akka remote actors from a GlassFish v3.1.2 server based application?

Tags: java, glassfish, akka

Akka remoting uses netty for it's client server framework. Does anyone know if I can get one end of this (the client) running in GlassFish v3.1.2?

Note: I'm interested in Akka 2.0.3 at the moment; running under jdk 1.6 as well for what it's worth (I don't mind compiling under 1.7 if necessary as play-mini Java may require)